# Find Phone Numbers

Tags: regex, parsing, scrapy, web-crawler

Looking to find phone numbers from multiple sites. 
So each site more than likely has it in different sections/classes/formats etc.

I am having a hard time finding phone numbers using regex or classes containing.

So any help is appreciated

my code is

```
def parse1(self, response):
hxs = Selector(response)
titles = hxs.xpath('/html/body')
items = []

for titles in titles:
    item = GenericCrawlerItem()

    item["phone"] = re.findall('/^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)\s*$/gm', response.body)

    item["phone"] = titles.xpath('//div[contains(text(), "tel")]/text()').extract()

    items.append(item)
    return items
```

Thanks!

edit: the formats i'm looking for will be mainly standard im suspecting such as:

```
(xxx)xxx-xxxx
xxx)xxx-xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxxx
xxx xxx xxxx
x(xxx)xxx-xxxx
x(xxx)xxx.xxxx
x.xxx.xxx.xxxx
+x(xxx)xxx-xxxx
+x.xxx.xxx.xxxx
```

Even if they aren't filling out every one of them. a couple would be super helpful!

Comment: You are only telling that there are different formats..specify the formats

Comment: Thanks for that heads up! Updated question

Comment: It is Python, no need for `/..../gm`, remove these slashes and `gm`. Try `r'(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)'`

Comment: That is getting me much closer! now just need to trim it down. I'm pretty new is there anyway you could break down that string so I can understand what each one is actually pulling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good enough answer it results such as

xxx.xxx.xxxx
or 
xxx-xxx-xxxx

def parse1(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath('/html/body')
    items = []

```
for titles in titles:
    item = GenericCrawlerItem()
    item["email"] = re.findall('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)
    item["website"] = response.url
    item["links"] = titles.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
    item["phone"] = re.findall(r'(\d{3}[-.()]\d{3}[-.]\d{4})', response.body)   ##results such as xxx xxx-xxxx or xxx.xxxx

    converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
    converter.ignore_links = True
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

Stand alone:

```
    item["phone"] = re.findall(r'(\d{3}[-.()]\d{3}[-.]\d{4})', response.body)   ##results such as xxx xxx-xxxx or xxx.xxxx
```

shoutout to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

`(\d\.?|\+\d\.?)?\(?\d{3}(\.| |-|\))\d{3}(\.| |-)\d{4}`

...will match all of your examples.

If you would like clarification on any part, or if it doesn't work for you, leave a comment and we can try to figure it out. A common reason this might not work is because something isn't being escaped properly (I developed this regex using Sublime Text, not Python - Python may require that some additional things be escaped here and there), or your regex engine differs from mine. For example, not all regex engines support the `\d` metacharacter to match numbers 0-9, and not all engines support the use of `{#}` to denote a specific number of characters to match.

Comment: Thanks for your help unfortunately im getting results such as:

[('', '-', '-')]

Comment: so after running your code I noticed it grabs much more effectively. So I think it is a combo of your regex with this syntax:

            item["phone"] = re.findall(r'((\d{3})[-.]*(\d{4}))', response.body)

this syntax example seemed to give me the best results but I don't fully understand. Actually trying to learn regex while typing this out lol

Comment: I think what's happening here is that I didn't have any false positives to test the regex against when writing it. Could you provide some examples of stuff it **shouldn't** match so it can get further refined? I tested Wiktor Stribiżew's regex on the same set of data I developed mine from, and his also worked great.

Comment: I learned all the regex I know from regexone.com, so I highly recommend heading over there and going through the levels! I occasionally pop back there for reference too.

Comment: TBH Im not sure what would define as shouldn't match. I guess any ratio of numbers containing less than 7 digits but no more than 11(since im looking for us numbers)

As well as digits that are combined across multiple strings. Since each number should be its own Xpath should be together.

Comment: Thanks! Ill check that out. I was looking around and found this cheat sheet which kinda helps: https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: alright so I found out that :

            item["phone"] = re.findall(r'(\d{3}[-.]\d{4})', response.body)

will find the (general) phone number outline so it will show results such as xxx-xxxx or xxx.xxxx

Slowly inching the way closer!

Comment: I think you'll get there!